# Why i am not getting datetimepicker in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker

Hi i want to give date and time as input in rails. so i used datetimepicker in app. here is the link i had followed to use datetimepicker. but i am not able to see datetimepicker in my input field. what will be the mistake? where i am struggling? please advise me if you have ideas

https://github.com/lubieniebieski/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails

**here is my application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require switchery
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require_tree .
```

**here is my application.css**

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require switchery
 *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

**here is my form.html**

```
<tr>
    <td class="col1"><label for="exam_date">Exam Date</label></td>
        <td class="col2">
            <%= text_field_tag :test_date%>
        </td>
</tr>
```

**here is my js**

```
$(function() {
    $('#test_date').datetimepicker();
  });
```

Please help me to get out from this problem. tried a lot but could not find where i am struggling. it might be repeated. but i refered So before posting. so pls dont do downvoting. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you import bootstrap and bootstrap-datetimepicker css?

Comment: yeah..just see my css file

Comment: @AnitaShalu have you tried adding `config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap-datetimepicker.js )` in your application.rb file

Comment: in your application.rb file, I already specified that

Comment: oh sorry just now saw that. let me do it

Comment: still it did not come

Comment: @AnitaShalu try `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap-datetimepicker.js bootstrap-datetimepicker.css )`, and you are using assets pipeline and you have executed `rake assets:precompile` command right?

Comment: sorry i am new to rails. so i dont know about this. give me a mint to execute this line

Comment: ran the above comment. but still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76540/discussion-between-sontya-and-anita-shalu).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this `bootstrap-datetimepicker` plugin has a dependency on `bootstrap.js`.

Update your `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require switchery
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require_tree .
```